# Gulp and Bower integration

Tags: javascript, automation, gulp, bower

I'm new to Gulp and Bower.  I'd like to copy specific files from `bower_components` to a `vendors` folder in my app.  For instance, **I'd like to only copy the `angular.js` file from `bower_components/angular` to `app/vendors/libs`**.

I am not sure which Gulp plugins to use.  I see that there's `gulp-bower`, `gulp-bower-files`, and `gulp-copy`.  I'm not sure which one to use, or if I should use all of them in the same task.

Is there an easy way to achieve this without specifying the `src` paths and `dest` paths for every single file I want to copy over?  I used to do that in Grunt and it was very tedious.  I am hoping Gulp will ease my pain (which it has done so far with other tasks).

Comment: `gulp.src('bower_components/angular/angular.js').pipe(gulp.dest('app/vendor/lib'))` copies the file for you.

Comment: Note that you can give multiple items to `gulp.src()` by passing an array (of patterns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gulp-bower-files` should do what you want. It will find the main files from your bower file. You can then pipe these to a new destination.

See the usage example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower-files

You would just need to change the destination for that to work as your task:

```
var gulpBowerFiles = require('gulp-bower-files');

gulp.task("bower-files", function(){
    gulpBowerFiles().pipe(gulp.dest("app/vendors/libs"));
});
```

Comment: Edited the answer since `gulp-bower-files` is deprecated.